# Getting MongoError DottedFieldName

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to perform a bulkWrite operation using mongoose but I get the following error:

`{"ok":0,"code":57,"codeName":"DottedFieldName","name":"MongoError"}`

However, I have no field names that have a dot in them. My mongoose version is 5.13.5 which internally uses mongodb version of 3.6.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue occurred as there was field name with the following name: '$schema'. Apparently, this caused the issue.